# SQL Server Activity Monitor - Resource Waits - Logging > 1400 ms/sec, how?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, activity-monitor

I have an SQL Server 2008 R2 server. I open "Activity Monitor", and inside the "Resource Waits" category, I see that the "Logging" category is taking up more than 1400 ms/sec.

That doesn't seem to be normal, what does that mean and how do I diagnose the cause?

**UPDATE:**

I ran this query, suggested by Shark:

```
select * from sys.dm_os_wait_stats order by wait_time_ms desc
```

and got these results:

```
wait_type                         waiting_tasks_count  wait_time_ms         max_wait_time_ms     signal_wait_time_ms
--------------------------------- ------------------- -------------------- --------------------- ---------------- 
LCK_M_IX                          3662                 102060386            31410                233
LAZYWRITER_SLEEP                  741527               63315760             305163               28805
WRITELOG                          3531635              42147142             4142                 309360
REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH       6327                 31676553             5038                 31676553
```

Comment: To get a more granular picture of your waits, run this query: `select * from sys.dm_os_wait_stats order by wait_time_ms desc`.  Each of those wait types have a direct meaning: compare them to this BOL reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179984.aspx).

Comment: Is it in line with what you have seen before (or is this the first time)?  At the risk of stating the obvious normal/abnormal are comparatives (usually) against an established baseline.

Comment: @Shark: I ran the query you suggested, you can see the top results in the original question. According to the documentation, this lock "Occurs when a task is waiting to acquire an Intent Exclusive (IX) lock".

Comment: You may want to run perfmon to analyze the physical disk queue length.  It looks like you may be bottlenecking when writing from the log cache to disk (the WRITELOG wait type).

Comment: @jl01: This is first time my system is running under load, and I'm trying to understand if there is an SQL bottleneck.

Comment: @Shark: % Disk Idle Time is around 15%, and Disk Queue Length averages in 1800.

Comment: Capture the Avg. Disk sec/Write for the PhysicalDisk object.  Let me know what that gives you.

Comment: @Shark: Sorry, the Disk Queue Length is not 1800, it's 1.8. The system locale is in French and it's confusing for me :) The Avg. Disk sec/Write is 0.014.

Comment: How long did you run that for??  You should probably create a data collector set and analyze when the instance is getting pegged.

Comment: @Shark: OK, ran this for longer. Avg Disk Queue Length - min 0.960, max 6, mean 2. That row is marked in red in the report. Avg Disk sec/Write min 0.009, max 0.032, mean 0.014.

Answer (score 4):

I would check disk health / performance for volumes holding your transaction logs. You are seeing a delay due to the [durability requirement](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/acid.htm), logging is backed up.

Check for I/O delays on tlog files in activity monitor as well.